# Force Rerender on FlatList when Screen Dimensions Change

Tags: react-native, native-base

I want to make a responsive App in React Native. I subscribe to Dimension changes in the container using this:

```
const RCTDeviceEventEmitter = require("RCTDeviceEventEmitter");

export interface Props {
    data: Array<any>;
}

export interface State {}

class MyContainer extends React.Component<Props, State> {

    _updateIfSelected() {
        if (...some more logic...) {
            this.forceUpdate();
        }
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            listener: null,
            updateIfSelected: this._updateIfSelected.bind(this),
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({
            listener: RCTDeviceEventEmitter.addListener("didUpdateDimensions", this.state.updateIfSelected),
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.state.listener.remove("didUpdateDimensions",this.state.updateIfSelected);
    }

    renderItem() {
        console.log("Rerendering Item")
        return <Text style={{ width: Dimensions.get("window").width }} >Some Text</Text>
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <FlatList
                data={this.props.data}
                keyExtractor={(_, i) => (i.toString())}
                renderItem={({item}) => this.renderItem(item)}
            />
    }
}
```

I was wondering how to force a FlatList to rerender its items, because the appearance needs to change when the screen is tilted. However, because the data doesn't change, the list won't be rerendered on screen tilts.

The Documentation provides a parameter called `extraData`:

```
By passing extraData={this.state} to FlatList we make 
sure FlatList itself will re-render when the state.selected 
changes. 
Without setting this prop, FlatList would not know it 
needs to re-render any items because it is also a 
PureComponent and the prop comparison will not show any changes
```

But I don't really understand what this is trying to say. Any Ideas how I can make the FlatList Rerender on Dimension changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a function to onLayout and check the dimensions when onLayout is called. I would recommend passing the function to a parent view. You could then setState in the function

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  _onLayout() { // I haven't tried this but I think this or something similar will work

    const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

    if(width > height) {
      this.setState(state => ({ ...state, orientation: 'landscape' }));
    } else {
      this.setState(state => ({ ...state, orientation: 'portrait' }));
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View onLayout={this._onLayout}>
      <FlatList
        data={this.props.data}
        keyExtractor={(_, i) => (i.toString())}
        renderItem={({item}) => this.renderItem(item)}
        extraData={this.state.orientation}
      />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: can u check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59355795/cant-update-state-immediately) please?