# Can't update state immediately?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have an two function in the first one I get all orders, the second one I get all rejected orders

So in the first function, I update the state based on second function state
and it's work well

but when I deleted an item from my Firebase console I can't see the updates immediately although I use `on("value",()=>{})`

So how can I handle it?

warning

> can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is
>   a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.

structure Arrays

```
let ordersArray = [
   {"snapshotKey":"-awdawadsdwwd","username":"Joe"},
   {"snapshotKey":"-badsdasdad","username":"Annna"},
   {"snapshotKey":"-dasQwaddas","username":"lee"}
]

let rejectedOrders = ["-awdawadsdwwd","-dasQwaddas"]
```

State

```
this.state = {
      orders: [],
      rejectedOrders: [],
    };


componentDidMount() {
    try {
      this.getRejectedOrders();
      this.fetchOrders();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('error', err);
    }
}
```

First Function

```
//Get all orders from DB

 fetchOrders = async () => {
    const {serviceName} = this.state;
    let uid = auth().currentUser.uid;
    const serviceStorage = await AsyncStorage.getItem('service');
    this.setState({serviceStorage});
    database()
      .ref(`Providers/CategoriesOrders/${serviceName || serviceStorage}`)
      .on('value', snapshot => {
        let orderArr = [];
        snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
          orderArr.push({
            snapshotKey: childSnapshot.key,
            username: childSnapshot.val().username,
          });
        });
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          orders: orderArr.filter(
            order =>
              !prevState.rejectedOrders.some(key => order.snapshotKey === key),
          ),
          loading: false,
        }));
      });
  };
```

Second Function

```
// get an array of rejected orders

  getRejectedOrders = () => {
    let uid = auth().currentUser.uid;
    const ref = database().ref(`Providers/users/${uid}`);
    ref.on('value', snapshot => {
      let rejectedOrders = snapshot.val().rejectedOrders;
      this.setState({rejectedOrders});
    });
  };
```

JSX

```
render(){
   return (
        <OrdersList
          data={this.state.orders}
          extraData={this.state}
          screenName="OrderHomeDetails"
        />
      );
}
```

component

```
const OrdersList = props => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        data={props.data}
        extraData={props.extraData}
        ListEmptyComponent={<EmptyList />}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        legacyImplementation={true}
        contentContainerStyle={{
          flexGrow: 1.2,
        }}
        renderItem={({item}) => {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() =>
                props.navigation.navigate(props.screenName, {
                  username: item.username,
                  snapshotKey: item.snapshotKey,
                })
              }
             >

                <View>
                  <Icon name="person" color="#AEACAC" size={20} />
                  <Text> {item.username}</Text>
                </View>

            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default withNavigation(OrdersList);
```

I think the issue with OrdersList component because when I log state in a call back after setState inside every function"fetchOrders() /getRejectedOrders()" I got the new rejected orders just not orders inside fetchOrders()

***though***

" When I add/delete data to rejected order array that's mean getRejectedOrders() just will change but fetchOrders() not because it's not related with these things 'it's got all orders at first time then filter it based on something and these orders did not change so why will update! "

EDIT ~ 1

```
fetchOrders = async () => {
    const {rejectedOrders, serviceName} = this.state;
    let uid = auth().currentUser.uid;
    const serviceStorage = await AsyncStorage.getItem('service');
    this.setState({serviceStorage});
    // await this.getRejectedOrders();
    database()
      .ref(`Providers/CategoriesOrders/${serviceName || serviceStorage}`)
      .on('value', snapshot => {
        let orderArr = [];
        snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
          orderArr.push({
            snapshotKey: childSnapshot.key,
            username: childSnapshot.val().username,
          });
        });
        this.setState(
          prevState => ({
            orders: orderArr.filter(
              order =>
                !prevState.rejectedOrders.some(
                  key => order.snapshotKey === key,
                ),
            ),
            loading: false,
          }),
          () => console.log(this.state.orders), // I don't git anything if i add or delete rejected orders
        );
        console.log(orderArr); // I don't git anything if i add or delete rejected orders
      });
  };



 getRejectedOrders = async () => {
    let uid = auth().currentUser.uid;
    database()
      .ref(`Providers/users/${uid}`)
      .on('value', snapshot => {
        let rejectedOrders = snapshot.val().rejectedOrders;
        this.setState({rejectedOrders}, () =>
          console.log(this.state.rejectedOrders), // here's i got every single time i add or delete item i can see it in console log
        );
      });
  };




 <OrdersList
          data={this.state.orders}
          extraData={this.state.orders.length} // i add it but it's not effected 
          screenName="OrderHomeDetails"
        />
```

Comment: How are you rendering the Orders on the UI? Can you show the JSX?

Comment: Check it again @AnandUndavia

Comment: I think `keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}` is the issue. Try changing it to `keyExtractor={() => Math.random()}`. If that works, then it means that `key` is same every time and that is why the list is not updated, you might want to come up with a proper function that extracts `key` from the `item`.

Comment: sadly i got this error `Failed child context type: Invalid child context 'virtualizedCell.cellKey' of type 'number' supplied to 'CellRenderer', expected 'string'.`

Comment: Try: `keyExtractor={() => Math.random().toString()}`

Comment: yeah i do it but my app crashed

Comment: Lol ok. How about this: `keyExtractor={(item) => item.snapshotKey}`

Comment: sadly the same :( i can't see any updates

Comment: Here's a warning i got after 3 min `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.`

Comment: @OliverD I guess the problem is with your `extraData` since you have passed in `this.state` so the shallow comparison would never be returning a change reflection just change it with length of your orders array. like `this.state.orders.length` and also verify if your state array is actually getting changed after firebase update. Please check if that helps.

Comment: @SurajMalviya I add it but does not work can you check my question again "Edit section"

Comment: @OliverD You need to add code to update orders after rejectedOrders got update. Currently, you just update `rejectedOrders` to state, it will do nothing with `orders`

Comment: @TuanLuong yeah that's what should be! but how can i handle it to reupdate orders

Answer (score 1):

You should update `orders` whenever `rejectedOrders` get updated. Besides, remember to `unsubcribe` listeners to avoid memory leak

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.allOrders = [];
    this.rejectedOrders = [];
    this.state = {
      orders: [],
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    database()
      .ref(`Providers/CategoriesOrders/${serviceName || serviceStorage}`)
      .off('value', this.ordersCallback);
    database()
      .ref(`Providers/users/${uid}`)
      .off('value', this.rejectedOrderCallback);
  }

  fetchOrders = async () => {
    ...
    database()
      .ref(`Providers/CategoriesOrders/${serviceName || serviceStorage}`)
      .on('value', this.ordersCallback);
  };

  getRejectedOrders = async () => {
    let uid = auth().currentUser.uid;
    database()
      .ref(`Providers/users/${uid}`)
      .on('value', this.rejectedOrderCallback);
  };

  ordersCallback = (snapshot) => {
    let orderArr = [];
    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
      orderArr.push({
        snapshotKey: childSnapshot.key,
        username: childSnapshot.val().username,
      });
    });
    this.allOrders = orderArr;
    this.updateData()
  }

  rejectedOrderCallback = (snapshot) => {
    this.rejectedOrders = snapshot.val().rejectedOrders;
    this.updateData();
  }

  updateData() {
    const orders = this.allOrders.filter(order => this.rejectedOrders.some(key => order.snapshotKey === key));
    this.setState({ orders });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but i got two error first one `Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined` 2- `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`

Comment: error 1, you need to update yourself, it is your turn to prepare your data when you get it from database. error 2, `FlatList` need each item to have a unique id, default it will get `id` field from each item. If your order item don't have `id`, you need to specify a unique value in `keyExtractor={order => order.<uniqueId>}`

Comment: thank u 1- but when I log the snapshot I can see all orders in my log! after refreshing the app twice or more it's work well,why!

Comment: It maybe the caching issue, you can try to restart metro bundle by `react-native start --reset-cache`

Comment: hmm, I do it but the issue still exists, when I comment componentWillUnmount() I can't see any error!

Comment: Any idea about this issue?

Comment: Sorry. So many update. Could you tell me your current problem and your latest code?

Comment: I add your code to my app expect componentsWillUnMount snippets because it's telling me an "undefined errors" but i think it's should exist because avoid memory leak "as u say"!

Comment: it is `componentWillUnmount` without `s`. You could check at https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount

Comment: Yeah sorry, it's a typo but still the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204413/discussion-between-tuan-luong-and-oliver-d).

Comment: @OliverD I think i know the problem. just update the answer. Check if it works for you

Comment: Hi Thank u, check last message on chat, please

Comment: It's a nice way, but i have some Q,  in `ordersCallBack()` you call `this.updateData(this.allOrders)` "with parameter" But in `rejectedOrdersCallback()` you don't pass any parameter to `this.updateData()` Why?

Comment: Glad that's a help, another thought  now you call this.updateData twice maybe that's will take a lot of memory or something!

Comment: it does not affect memory, `updateData` just prepare data for display from `this.allOrders` and `this.rejectedOrders`.

Comment: Well, sorry it's not my cup of tea but he was asking you in the discussion about your answer he wants an explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can use flag isMounted to check when use setState. About the problem state not update immediately, you can use ref.current to see updated immediately after the change.